# How to do JOIN query and not ignore records with NULL values?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables in my Postgres database:

users

```
 Column |         Type          
--------+-----------------------
 id     | integer               
 name   | character varying(50)
```

products

```
   Column    |         Type          
-------------+-----------------------
 id          | integer               
 name        | character varying(50) 
 user_id     | integer               
 category_id | integer
```

categories

```
 Column |         Type          
--------+-----------------------
 id     | integer               
 name   | character varying(50)
```

Example data in users

```
id | name
---+------
1  | John
2  | Sara
```

Example data in products

```
id | name           | user_id | category_id
---+----------------+---------+------------
1  | iPhone 8       | 1       | 1
2  | MacBook        | 1       | 2
3  | Fidget Spinner | 1       | NULL
4  | Dell XPS       | 1       | 2
5  | Samsung S8     | 2       | 1
```

Example data in categories

```
id | name
---+-----------
1  | Mobile Phones
2  | Laptops
3  | Toys
```

I have a route in my Rails project and I want the action for this route to return result like this:

```
[
   {
      "category":"Mobile Phones",
      "products":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"iPhone 8"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"Laptops",
      "products":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"MacBook"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Dell XPS"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"Toys",
      "products":[

      ]
   }
]
```

Basically, when John calls this endpoint, he will see all his products. The main thing here, I want to show all categories regardless they have products under them or not.

Please advice the best and most efficient Rails ActiveRecord or SQL statement for this.

Comment: gonna go out on a whim with left join

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, and show us your query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer join the user's products to the categories in order to get all categories:

```
select
  c.name as category_name,
  p.id as product_id,
  p.name as product_name
from categories c
left join products p on p.category_id = c.id and p.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is most closest to what I want. Appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

Go with left outer join. It will also return null values -

For example, for table t1 and table t2 -

```
  SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.a = t2.c
ORDER BY t1.a
```

Comment: @Zulhilmi Zainudin: It seems you haven't understood this answer. You want all categories even when the user has no products in the category. The answer is: use a left outer join. Confused kangaroo just gave you the type of query you need rather than a tailor-made query for you, probably because you did not show any effort to write a query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the records which do not exist in the master/lookup table then you can use the left/right join

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = p.category_id
```